# VBA “Runtime Error 1004 Application-Defined Or Object-Defined Error” While Assigning Value To Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign a string value to 3 cells. I have checked that the macro is at module level, current sheet is activated and it is not referring to any non-existent cells. The sheet is also not protected. Still not sure why it is throwing this error.

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Bank (Pivot)")

Sheets("Bank (Pivot)").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Interest"
Sheets("Bank (Pivot)").Cells(1, 5).Value = "Deposit"
Sheets("Bank (Pivot)").Cells(1, 9).Value = "Withdrawal"
```

Comment: Is the sheet protected?

Comment: No. Sheet is also not protected. Forgot to mention that in the question description.

Comment: Yes :(. Just tried that as well.

Comment: Are the cells you're trying to change, part of a Pivot table?

Comment: Yes. The cells I am assigning values to are part of a pivot table filter. But this code was working earlier. Recently, I did some cleanup and it stopped working.

Comment: You should work with the [`PivotTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable) properties and methods.

Comment: How do I assign value to the cell then? Please help! This sheet is powering a number of different sheets.

Comment: Is your sheet still named "Bank (Pivot)", you could try and see if `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,2).Value = "Interest"` will work

Comment: @tnavidi - no, that will not work.

Comment: This is solved! I was trying to assign "Interest" as a filter when the new data did not have any item of that category in the pivot data. Thanks everyone!